# Trouble accessing network drives in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, authentication

Running Windows 7 Professional.

I am experiecing problems accessing network drives (shares) on my local netowork.
I have a LaCiE network drive - the Windows XP machine can access it without problems.
I can see the computer name for the network drive but a pop-up comes up asking me for logon credentials.  I enter the **exact** credentials I used when setting up the share on the web-based control for the network drive - but still can't logon.

What do I do?